# Can I use `sortrows`s compare function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, compare

I have a matrix sorted by the built-in function `sortrows`... Now, for some algorithm, I would like to compare two rows of this matrix with the same compare function that `sortrows` uses. Is there any?

Edit, example:

`sortrows` has to figure out whether `[1 2 3]` belongs before or after `[2 3 4]` in order to make a valid sort. I want to figure this out myself, i.e. have a function that figures this out for me. The result might be in `{0,-1,1}` (equal, smaller, greater) or just in `{0,1}` (equal, smaller). I don't care about this detail.

Comment: What do you mean "the same compare function of `sort`? `Sort`.... sorts, not compares, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, but sort has to have a way to figure out if [1 2 3] belongs before or after [2 3 4]... I want to use this way myself

Comment: I think you want `issorted([1 2 3; 2 3 4],'rows')`

Comment: @LuisMendo I think, you are right, thank you! Write it as an answer and I sign it

Comment: Just to make sure, you sorted the matrix with `sortrows`, right? `sort` on a matrix would sort each column independently, which is a different thing

Comment: @LuisMendo I have used `sort`... but sounds like I should use `sortrows`. Invaluable comments you are making!

Comment: @IceFire Heh. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `issorted([1 2 3; 2 3 4],'rows')`. This gives `1` if the first row precedes the second in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which is the order used by `sortrows`.